# Is there a way to scale negative y-axis tick differently from the positive in nivo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, nivo-react

Is there a way to create a chart like the one on the image in nivo? I need to scale the negative tick values on the y-axis differently from the positive tick values. Positive tick step is much smaller, but the scale should be the same.

[image: different positive and negative plot]

I tried to use the [stream chart](https://nivo.rocks/stream/) but I didn't find a solution for setting different scales. Also, the stream chart doesn't show the value from 0. So this would be more like a filled [line chart](https://nivo.rocks/line/) where I would need to scale the positive part differently from the negative part.

Is this possible to achieve with the [nivo](https://nivo.rocks/) library?